# Boost add_file_log issue

Tags: boost

when setting the keywords::rotation_size option in add_file_log method, my code, which is multi-threaded, crashes when the file gets to this size.
Is there a methodology I can use to determine why this capability fails?
The other programs I generate, which are all serial, no threads, works as advertised.

moving add_file_log code further down in the chain, but no changes to results

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.